# Problems on Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the following system of linear congruences :
$x \equiv 4\ (\textrm{mod}\ 12)$
$x \equiv 7\ (\textrm{mod}\ 21)$
$x \equiv 10\ (\textrm{mod}\ 15)$

Answer (score 1):

$x\equiv4\bmod12\implies x\equiv1\bmod3$ and $x\equiv0\bmod 4$.

$x\equiv7\bmod21\implies x\equiv1\bmod3$ and $x\equiv0\bmod 7$.

$x\equiv10\bmod15\implies x\equiv1\bmod3$ and $x\equiv0\bmod5$.

So we have $x\equiv1 \bmod 3$ and $x\equiv0\pmod {4\times7\times5=140}$.

Can you solve this $\bmod 420$?

Answer (score 1):

$$x \equiv 4\mod12 \implies x=12a+4 \quad \color{red}{\text{(1.)}}$$

$$x \equiv 7\mod21\quad \color{blue}{\text{(2.)}}$$

Substituting $\text{(  1. ) }$ in  $\text{ ( 2.) }$,

$$12a+4 \equiv 7\mod21 \implies a =  2+7b \quad \color{green}{\text{(3.)}}$$

$$x \equiv 10\mod15 \quad \color{orange}{\text{(4.)}}$$

$$84b + 28 \equiv 10\mod15 \implies b = 5c+3$$

Hence $x = 12(2+7(5c+3)) + 4 \implies \boxed{x = 420c+280}$